# graphs with specific radius and diameter

Tags: graph-theory

Can anybody help me in finding out the family of non-bipartite graphs where diameter is 2 and radius is 1.

The only graphs that came into my mind are wheel graphs. Is there any other graph that I am missing? Thanks a lot.

Comment: $C_4$ and $C_6^2$ both have radius greater than $1$. Think carefully about what form the graph needs to take if the radius is $1$.

Comment: @EuYu yes u r right.... i wil edit my questn. thanks

Comment: As a hint, I feel that it's important to reiterate the fact that the graph has radius $1$. These graphs must take on a very special general form. Can you tell me what it means for a graph to have radius $1$?

Comment: @EuYu It means there exist a vertex 'v' which is adjacent to all other vertices of the graph. and the eccentricity of this vertex will give the radius of the graph. Am I right sir?

Comment: Yes, there must exist a central vertex $v$ in your graph. That forms the basic skeleton for your family of graphs. Can you think of how to complete it?

Comment: @EuYu Means central vertex must b adjacent to all other vertices and there must be atleast one odd cycle, then I will get the required graph. Am I right sir?

Comment: Yes, that's essentially it. I've included an answer for completeness.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since your graph has radius $1$ there must be a central vertex $v$ to which all other vertices are connected. Therefore the underlying backbone of your graph family are the star graphs $S_n$ (with $n+1$ total vertices). Clearly we require $n > 1$.

The graphs in the family must be obtained from adding edges to the star graphs. Note that adding any edge will result in the graph being non-bipartite by completing a triangle with the central vertex.

Also note that the graph cannot be complete since that violates the condition of the diameter being $2$. Conversely, it is easy to check that any non-complete graph obtained from the star graph has diameter $2$.

Therefore the graphs in your family are precisely the graphs obtained from the star graphs $S_n$ by adding $k$ edges with $0 < k < \binom{n}{2}$.

Comment: thanks a lot... its clear now :)